# How Can I play audio in docker container with firefox?

Tags: docker

I got firefox working in a docker container but I can't hear audio visiting YouTube. The volume is at max. Below is my Dockerfile:

```dockerfile
FROM linuxmintd/mint20-amd64
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install iputils-ping net-tools xauth x11-apps firefox pulseaudio alsa-utils sox -y
RUN xauth add geekfreak/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  9b68dc97c89fb50bc405a86c8d4b58b5
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash geek
CMD ["/usr/bin/firefox","www.google.com"]
```

After I built the image, I ran the command below.

```sh
docker run -it -e DISPLAY --net=host --name firefox --user 1000 --device=/dev/snd lm20:1.1
```

firefox opens. But visiting youtube I can't hear any audio. Is there a fix for this or docker can't play audio in a container? Thanks

Comment: Can you hear any audio in the container?  Is there a way to test a different source to make sure you are getting audio in general and its not just something to do with youtube?

Comment: probably easiest way would be using [`x11docker`](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker) to start the container. `x11docker` does all the setup for a seemless integration for you.

Comment: It's not the most secure but a quick and dirty solution may just be to mount the entire /dev directory as a volume. I haven't tested this myself though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did share the `--device=/dev/snd` of the host with the container but the user in the container probably has not the necessary permissions to access the device directly or even if so the device is already occupied by a host process.

Instead of trying to access the hardware directly from the container you should rather use the client/server architecture of `pulseaudio`, i.e., expose a connection to the `pulseaudio` server - running as normal desktop process directly on the host - to `pulseaudio` client running in the container.

The [`x11docker` wiki](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker/wiki/Container-sound:-ALSA-or-Pulseaudio#pulseaudio-with-shared-socket) has a detailed guide for this.

Comment: Oh my gosh! It worked. that wiki article you provided was simple and to the point. I read other articles on this and they were complicated and confusing to follow. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: May I ask if you or anybody else put all the stuff necessary to get this running in a docker-compose.yml? I'd highly appreciate that. Thank you.

Comment: It depends on your distro, but it's unlikely you need to manually create a socket for pulseaudio, there's going to be one at `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/pulse/native`, so this is enough to add to docker run `-v "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/pulse/native":/tmp/pulse.socket`