# Python Django in Docker - Input device error

Tags: python, django, docker, digital-ocean

I've tried to deploy my Django App on DigitalOcean App Platform. Due to using PyAudio I had to use Dockerfile, because python3-pyaudio requires "apt-get". I've created Dockerfile and successfull installed PyAudio. Unfortunetly I've got an error "OSError: No Default Input Device Available".

```
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:35] /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydub/utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:35]   warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:35] Not Found: /
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: No such file or directory
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib conf.c:5703:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM sysdefault
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: No such file or directory
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib conf.c:5703:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM sysdefault
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround21
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround40
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround41
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround50
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround51
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: No such file or directory
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib conf.c:5703:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: No such file or directory
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib conf.c:5703:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_id returned error: No such file or directory
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib conf.c:5703:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM dmix
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] Cannot connect to server request channel
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] jack server is not running or cannot be started
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] Internal Server Error: /voice/
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] Traceback (most recent call last):
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40]     response = get_response(request)
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40]     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 104, in view
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40]     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 143, in dispatch
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40]     return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40]   File "/app/recognize/views.py", line 54, in get
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40]     txt = self.getText()
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40]   File "/app/recognize/views.py", line 39, in getText
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40]     with sr.Microphone() as source:
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 87, in __init__
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40]     device_info = audio.get_device_info_by_index(device_index) if device_index is not None else audio.get_default_input_device_info()
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyaudio/__init__.py", line 812, in get_default_input_device_info
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40]     device_index = pa.get_default_input_device()
[speech-to-text] [2024-02-05 22:42:40] OSError: No Default Input Device Available
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
# Use the official Python image as the base image
FROM python:3.10-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install any dependencies specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install gunicorn

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    apt-utils \
    portaudio19-dev \
    python3-dev \
    gcc

# Install python3.X-pyaudio (adjust X to your Python version)
RUN apt-get install python3-pyaudio

# Install pyaudio for the Python environment
RUN pip install pyaudio

# Expose port 8000 to the outside world
EXPOSE 8000

# Command to run your application
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--worker-tmp-dir", "/dev/shm", "speechai.wsgi:application"]
```

Has anyone encountered this type of problem? Unfortunately I cannot find any solution.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Can I play audio in docker container with firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74352939/how-can-i-play-audio-in-docker-container-with-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your application, so I created a simple script to replicate the problem. It just plays a WAV file. With the existing setup this script produces essentially the same error.

`audio.py`

```
import wave
import sys

import pyaudio

CHUNK = 1024

with wave.open('StarWars3.wav', 'rb') as wf:
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                    channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                    rate=wf.getframerate(),
                    output=True)

    while len(data := wf.readframes(CHUNK)):
        stream.write(data)

    stream.close()

    p.terminate()
```

Created a requirements file for the Python packages.

`requirements.txt`

```
gunicorn==21.2.0
PyAudio==0.2.14
```

And trimmed down your Docker configuration.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        apt-utils \
        portaudio19-dev \
        python3-dev \
        gcc \
        wget

COPY requirements.txt /app

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

COPY . /app

# Get some sample audio.
RUN wget -q https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/SoundFiles/StarWars3.wav

CMD ["python3", "audio.py"]
```

The key though is that you need to share the host's audio device with the container. You do this via the `--device` argument to `docker run`.

```
docker run -it --device /dev/snd ...
```

With this setup you should hear a dramatic few seconds of audio.

I installed `wget` to download the audio sample. You can remove it from the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: I've tried with --device flag. Unfortunetly I've got still this error. I've got problem with "input device", because I need to record an audio.

Comment: Okay, unless you share some minimal code that reproduces your issue I cannot really help you more. Did you try out the code I provided above to validate that at least play back works for you? I'd say that this is an important first step. Get playback working. Once that is done then we can resolve the recording issue.

Can you please share a minimal Python script that illustrates what you are wanting to do?